# Crop image using croppie in Laravel form image didn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, forms, croppie

trying to crop and save image with croppie library not from ajax but from for data because i have another data to send , Image cropped  and saved in database but it is corrupted

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adUe2.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XLIi.png)

there are my controller and js code

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label> {{trans('words.upload_about_img')}}</label> <br>
        <label>Select File</label>
        <label id="projectinput7" class="file center-block">
            <input type="file" name="image" id="image-input" accept="image/*">
            <input type="hidden" name="cropped-image" id="cropped-image-input">
            <span class="file-custom"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="image-container">
</div>
```

```
 // Initialize Croppie image
    var image = $('#image-container').croppie({
        enableExif: true,
        viewport: {
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            type: 'square'
        },
        boundary:{
            width:400,
            height:400
        }  
    });

    // Bind update event to update hidden input with cropped image data
    image.on('update', function (croppedImage) {
        $('#cropped-image-input').val(croppedImage);
    });

    // When file input changes, load the image into the Croppie container
    $('#image-input').on('change', function () {
        var input = this;
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                image.croppie('bind', {
                    url: e.target.result
                });
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    });
```

```
 $imageData = $request->input('cropped-image');
        $imageName = uniqid() . '.png';
        $imagePath = public_path('images/' . $imageName);
        file_put_contents($imagePath, base64_decode(str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $imageData)));

$about = About::create([
            'id' => Auth::id(),
            'description' => $request->description,
            'about_img' => 'images/'.$imageName,
            'mission' => $request->mission,
            'vision' => $request->vision,
            'our_value' => $request->our_value,



]);
```

Comment: Is your `$imageData` in base64? If it is, what do you get when you use something like `echo base64_decode($imageData);` in your backend? Or, before sending it to your backend, you can use `console.log(atob(yourBase64Data))` to check what you're actually sending. This is just a guess, but maybe your `$imageData` is malformed in some way.

Comment: @FiddlingAway I think it was not sent when try to return  $croppedImage in backend I got nothing and cropped-image: in payload empty but I can't find why

Comment: How are you sending the base64 string to your backend (AJAX, submitting the form, some other way)? The reason that I'm asking - I can't see that in the code you provided. If it's AJAX - check the Network tab of your browser's Developer console, and activate the XHR filter (should be at the top of the Network tab). Then, submit your image to your server, and check if the Network tab shows that AJAX call. If it's not there, that's where the problem is (server not getting your base64 string). If it's there, click on it, and check the Request tab in the right-hand sidepanel.

Comment: @FiddlingAway without ajax it is by submitting form

Comment: Try console.log(croppedImage) in Update event and show me the content of it

Comment: What do you get with `print_r($_POST)` in the blade which is getting the contents of your form?